# Linq Filter Collection Inside Collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

'I have a collection with these details

```
Class Team
{
string TeamName;
Int TeamId;
List<matches>Match
}

class Matches
{
    String MatchName;
    Int Season;
}
```

I have around 16 teams and I need to select a particular team's data greater than year 1998. Which is the best approach? I tried using .Any but it skips and only taking the season filter condition. Any help?

Comment: Well you want to select team A and all it's match because one is >1998. or you want team A but only with the match that are >1998?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could update your code sample so that it has proper indentation, and it compiles. It would be even better if you could provide a [mcve] with sample data (in code) and the **exact** results you are trying to generate.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding you want the list of all team with a match that matches a condition but with a list of match filter based on this condition. With the following data:

```
var allteams = new List<Team> {
    new Team
    {
        TeamName = "FooBar SO",
        TeamId = 1,
        Matchs = new List<Match>
        {
            new Match{ MatchName="ok" , Season=100 },
            new Match{ MatchName="notOk" , Season=10 }
        }
    },
    new Team
    {
        TeamName = "Other SO",
        TeamId = 2,
        Matchs = new List<Match>
        {
            new Match{ MatchName="nope" , Season=20 },
            new Match{ MatchName="notOk" , Season=10 }
        }
    }
};
```

1/. All team with at least one match matching the condition.
 The list of match of the team is preserved.

```
var teamsFilterOnSeason 
    = allteams.Where(t => t.Matchs.Any(m => m.Season >= 100));
```

result:

```
 TeamName: FooBar SO,
 TeamId: 1,
 Matchs: 
 [
    { MatchName: ok, Season: 100 },
    { MatchName: notOk, Season: 10 }
 ]
```

2/. All team with at least one match matching the condition.
The list of match is filter with the condition.

```
var teamsWithSeasonFilter 
    = allteams
        .Where(t => t.Matchs.Any(m => m.Season >= 100))
        .Select(
            t => 
            new Team {
                TeamName = t.TeamName,
                TeamId = t.TeamId,
                Matchs= t.Matchs
                            .Where(m=> m.Season >= 100)
                            .ToList()
            }
        );
```

result:

```
TeamName: FooBar SO,
TeamId: 1,
Matchs: 
[
    { MatchName: ok, Season: 100 }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

lets say you have teams object, you can use Linq like the following....

```
 var result =teams.Where(x=> x.Match.Any(y=>y.Season>1998) && x.TeamId==123);
```

I think you missed compare operator `==`

Comment: Nope that was a typo here, Sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Team
{
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public List<Match> Matches { get; set; }
}

public class Match
{
    public string MatchName { get; set; }
    public int Season { get; set; }
}

var teams = new List<Team> {
    new Team
    {
        TeamName = "Team 1",
        TeamId = 1,
        Matches = new List<Match>
        {
             new Match{ MatchName="Match 11" , Season=1 },
             new Match{ MatchName="Match 12" , Season=2 }
        }
    },
    new Team
    {
        TeamName = "Team 2",
        TeamId = 2,
        Matches = new List<Match>
        {
            new Match{ MatchName="Match 21" , Season=1 },
            new Match{ MatchName="Match 22" , Season=2 }
        }
    }
};

List<Match> team1seazon2 = teams.Where(t => t.TeamId == 1).SelectMany(t => t.Matches).Where(m => m.Season == 2).ToList();
```

Comment: The end result should teams collection, here it will be match collection.

Comment: You are right. The quality of the question is quite low, but I should have figured that out. If you change the last line to: `List<Team> team1seazon2 = teams.Where(t => t.TeamId == 1 && t.Matches.Any(m => m.Season == 2)).ToList();` then you will have the list of teams that played in Season 2. Be aware, that the matches list will also contain other matches of that team (from other seasons).

Answer (score 0):

To get the team data for any team with a season greater than 1998:

`var result = teams.Where(x => x.matches.Any(t => t.Season > 1998));`